# How to use <ul> to display scrolling contents?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I came across https://minimill.co/ and saw it as a good example to what I'm trying to achieve.

I made an attempt to display the listed items like the site:

```css
.wrap {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;

    li {
        background-color: green;
    }
}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 66rem;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.right-details {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    box-size: border-box;
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.left-img {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 66.66666%;

    img {
        width: 50px;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrap">
    <li>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="left-img">
                <img src="/assets/img/macbook-image.png"/>
            </div>
            <h2 class="right-details">
                Item 1
            </h2>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>
                Item 2
            </h2>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But the first `<li>` disappears.

How can I display my contents in one long scroll-like how https://minimill.co/ is doing? Am I doing it correctly as implemented on the site? Any guidance or insight on mimicking it more closely would be appreciated.

Comment: you mean something more like this: https://jsfiddle.net/c4hf6fhq/ ?

Comment: do you mean the smooth page scroll effect? http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/full/dpBMVP/

Comment: `wrap{li{}}`??? See if you pasted correct CSS.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu It is SCSS

Comment: Okay :D I guess minimill is using JS which is giving li position to trigger the effect.

Comment: @MartHaarman That's what I have. I have to create a page and display my contents in a long scroll like the one I referenced. I tried copying it but having troubles so far

Comment: @mlegg I have to create a page and display my contents in a long scroll like the one I referenced.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c4hf6fhq/1/ this might be what you are looking for? it is the basics in what you can add things yourself such as nice smooth transitions

Comment: Jo Ko that is a one page website.

Comment: @MartHaarman I'm just trying to figure out how to implement like how they display the content in one whole page with `<ul>`, without the background color change.

Comment: @mlegg Aware so trying to figure out how they display the content in one whole page with `<ul>`, without the background color change.

Answer (score 11):

You should use `min-height:100vh` instead of `height:100vh;`. Please check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattonit/gwpqjou3/1/)

```js
// select all elements with data-background attribute
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("[data-background]");
// create empty array
var heights = [];
// use for loop to "discover" all of the elements in lis array
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
  // get element's distance from top
  var distanceFromTop = lis[i].offsetTop;
  // get value from data-backgrount attribute
  var background = lis[i].getAttribute("data-background");
  // push background and distance to heights array
  heights.push({background: background, distance: distanceFromTop});
};

// check if page was scrolled
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(evt){
    // if page was scrolled what's the user's distance from top
 var distanceFromTop = this.scrollY;
 
  // find distances in heights array
  heights.forEach(function(height) {
    // check if user reached another checkpoint
    if(height.distance < distanceFromTop) {
            // if so, change the background to value that we got from data-background attribute
            // 
   document.body.className = height.background;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  transition: background-color .8s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .8s ease;
}

body.blue { background-color: #39f; }
body.red { background-color: #FF351A; }
body.dark { background-color: #222; }
body.yellow { background-color: #fd3; }
body.deep-blue { background-color: #417ABA; }
body.white { background-color: #fff; }
body.beige { background-color: #F7D693; }

li {
  min-height: 100vh;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<body class="blue">
  <ul>
    <li data-background="blue"></li>
    <li data-background="red"></li>
    <li data-background="dark"></li>
    <li data-background="yellow"></li>
    <li data-background="deep-blue"></li>
    <li data-background="white"></li>
    <li data-background="beige"></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

You should use `min-height:100vh` instead of `height:100vh;`. Please check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattonit/gwpqjou3/1/)

Comment: Appreciate the response! Before I accept the answer and upvote, as a learning purpose, could you comment on the Javascript portion for clarification? Also, could you show how they are displaying the content with the picture and description per color? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you but how are they displaying the content with the picture and description per color?

Answer (score 8):

So easiest approach seems to be using `height: 100vh;`, which stands for *hundredths of the viewport height.* (see: [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/viewport.html)).

```css
body, ul, li {
  height: 100%;
}
li { height: 100vh; }
ul { list-style-type: none; }
.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: yellow; }
.c { background-color: black; }
.d { background-color: green; }
.e { background-color: orange; }
.f { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="a"></li>
        <li class="b"></li>
        <li class="c"></li>
        <li class="d"></li>
        <li class="e"></li>
        <li class="e"></li>

    </ul>
</body>
```

**But:** it is not supported for IE <= 10 and Android <= 4.3.
(see: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)).

What [minimill](https://minimill.co/) does on their website is using **two** `<ul>` tags:

1. `<ul class="backgrounds">` which has it's `position: fixed` (love self-descriptive class names);
2. `<ul class="sections">` which stores actual content of the web site;
3. and the **key** to make it all work: `.sections li` with `padding: 16rem 0 0;` (which means: `padding-top: 16rem;`). It is all customized to the need of images they use.

See here:

```css
body, li, ul { /* RESET */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
    line-height: 1.5;
    position: relative;
}
ul { list-style-type: none; }
.backgrounds {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.backgrounds li {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: .5s ease opacity;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.sections {
    position: relative;
    transition: .5s ease opacity;
    z-index: 2;
}
.sections li { padding: 16rem 0 0; }

.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: yellow; }
.c { background-color: black; }
.d { background-color: green; }
.e { background-color: orange; }
.f { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<body>
    <ul class="backgrounds">
        <li class="a"></li>
        <li class="b"></li>
        <li class="c"></li>
        <li class="d"></li>
        <li class="e"></li>
        <li class="f"></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="sections">
      <li class="a"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet;</p></li>
      <li class="b"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet;</p></li>
      <li class="c"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet;</p></li>
      <li class="d"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet;</p></li>
      <li class="e"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet;</p></li>
      <li class="f"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet;</p></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Furthermore, all the background swaping is made with JS.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the example you provided, the first list item should be `height: 100vh;` and the height of the other items will be based on the content itself. In the code below, I added a bit of script that scrolls from the first item to the second when the "Scroll Down" anchor tag is clicked.

Check out my [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Tsekwi/36qqzh6j/).

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<ul id="wrap">
  <li>
    <div>
      <h2>Item 1</h2>
      <div id="scroll-down">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Scroll Down</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="scrollto">
    <div>
      <h2>Item 2</h2>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h2>Item 3</h2>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Here's the SCSS:**

```
$width: 100%;
$height: 100%;

html, body {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
  li {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: $width;
  }
  li:first-child {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  li:not(:first-child) {
    min-height: 400px;
  }
  li:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
  li:last-of-type {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
#scroll-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  width: $width;
}
#scroll-down a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

**Here's a bit of JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#scroll-down").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#scrollto").offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at https://minimill.co/ is in fact two ul's, one is being used to show the background color and the other is used to show the content. It seems that the ul associated with the background color does have a javascript event listener that tracks your the window scroll and depending on what content is being shown, the corresponding background color is displayed.

[image]

Yes, you are on the right path. In fact, this particular page has a very large top padding (16rem = 16 * 16px = 256px) to centralize the content and depending on the window size, it has different css classes.

[image]
[image]

Regarding your question, I did try it and the first item appears to me.

Comment: Before I accept the answer and upvote, do you mind showing one working with the same properties? Mine for some reason still doesn't show up.

Comment: Just checking in to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what from Minimill's site, that you want to achieve. Minimill does have that fancy background-color-change, which is an event-listener - but it sounds like, that you just want to have the sections as they do?

Such as:

```
Section about: We are Minimill
Section about: Redspread
Section about: KPCB
...
...
```

If it's just that you want to have sections in the same way, then that can achieve quite easily. If you haven't heard of it, then I would point you in the direction of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which is a CSS-library that does A LOT for you. When I first heard of it, then I thought 'That sounds like a hassle to look into', - but it's really quite magical, how much time you save by spending a couple of hours understanding how it works.

You can also code the whole thing yourself, such as: https://jsfiddle.net/2awczzcc/2/

And here's the code:

```
<ul class="wrap">
<li>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="left-container">
   <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/fantheories/images/4/43/Toy-Story-Theme-Song-6.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140624192735"/>
  </div>

  <div class="right-container">
   <h2>
   Item 1
   </h2>
   <p>
   Text text text.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>

<li>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="left-container">
   <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/fantheories/images/4/43/Toy-Story-Theme-Song-6.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140624192735"/>
  </div>

  <div class="right-container">
   <h2>
   Item 2
   </h2>
   <p>
   Text text text.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>

<li>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="left-container">
   <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/fantheories/images/4/43/Toy-Story-Theme-Song-6.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140624192735"/>
  </div>

  <div class="right-container">
   <h2>
   Item 2
   </h2>
   <p>
   More text, more text, more text.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
.wrap {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

  .wrap li {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both; 
    display: block; 
    min-height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .wrap li:first-child {
    background-color: green;
  }

  .wrap li:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .wrap li:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: yellow;
  }

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 66rem;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.left-container {
  float: left; 
  width: 48%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right-container {
  float: right; 
  width: 48%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-container img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 25px 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/night11/7fcqzdmy/2/)
 
HTML Code:

```
<ul>
<li id="one" data-color="#16A085">
<h2>Section One</h2>
</li>
<li id="two" data-color="#C0392B">
  <h2>Section Two</h2>
</li>
<li id="three" data-color="#ff44AD">
  <h2>Section Three</h2>
</li>
<li id="four" data-color="#f88f18">
  <h2>Section Four</h2>
</li>
<li id="five" data-color="#E91E63">
  <h2>Section Five</h2>
</li>

</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() {

  if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#one").position().top) {
    $('body').css('background', $("#one").attr("data-color"));
  };

  if ($(document).scrollTop() > $("#two").position().top) {
    $('body').css('background', $("#two").attr("data-color"))
  };

  if ($(document).scrollTop() > $("#three").position().top) {
    $('body').css('background', $("#three").attr("data-color"))
  };

  if ($(document).scrollTop() > $("#four").position().top) {
    $('body').css('background', $("#four").attr("data-color"))
  };
   if ($(document).scrollTop() > $("#five").position().top) {
    $('body').css('background', $("#five").attr("data-color"))
  };

});
```

CSS

```
li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  background: #16A085;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 550ms ease;
  will-change: background;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add `height: 100vh;` to the style for LI and you should be set.

[Working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgoLZJ) (I had to modify the CSS a bit since codepen doesn't support `sass`).

If I misunderstood the question and that's not what you're looking for, let me know.

Comment: It's not missing a `}`. the OP is using `sass` and that's how it works.

Comment: @claudios I'll edit my answer then. It was incompatible with codepen though so I had to move some things around in order to provide a working example of what they're trying to achieve with the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of ul or your div.
Also, set overflow to auto:

```
<ul style="width: 300px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
  <li>items</li>
  <li>items</li>
```